# How to get Waledac and Storm P2P botnets

Tags: malware

I am going to conduct a research on p2p botnet detection based on their network behavior. Would you help me how to get these botnets sample. 
Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

If you're conducting malware research based on network behavior, why not set up a honeypot to collect samples?  Failing that, there's all kinds of places on the web to find malware samples.  I'll leave that to you.

Cheers